# jQuery - clone form elements and change labels for

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a problem - I want to clone a part of HTML form but I have no idea how can I change label `for` attribute.

I'm using code like this:

```
<script>

    $('#add-service').click(function () {
        $('.services div.service:last').clone(true)
        .find(':input').each(function () {
            this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function (str, p1) {
                return '[' + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + ']';
            })

            this.id = this.name

        }).end().find('label').each(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
            $(this).attr('for', function (index, old) {
                old.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function (str, p1) {
                    return '[' + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + ']';
                });
            })
        }).end().insertAfter('.services div.service:last');
    });

</script>
```

but `for` attribute for `label` is not updated (but `background-color` is)

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1obmrb10/)

Questions:

1. How to update above code to make `for` for label also be updated
2. Is it possible to rewrite this code to make it shorter

Comment: Have to explain a little better what you are trying to change about the `for` attribute. Just the index, or the index and the name?

Comment: @Adjit Original `for` is `services[0][name]`, I would like it to be `services[1][name]` for 1st added row, `services[2][name]` for 2nd added row and so on

Comment: Reagrding question #2, I think that your code is short enough. Trying to make it shorter would be overkill and could make it really hard to understand (also not sure if possible).

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo Thanks for your opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it right, but you are missing a return statement.

```
$(this).attr('for', function (index, old) {
    return old.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function (str, p1) {
        return '[' + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + ']';
    });
})
```

Remember, you have 2 nested functions and each return only applies to the function you are currently inside.

Comment: Thanks. That was it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the new value after running `replace`.

```
$(this).attr('for', function (index, old) {
  return old.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function (str, p1) {
    return '[' + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + ']';
  });
})
```